# Pendulum with flexible connecting rod: synchrony in nature

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, frequency, vibrations, coupled-oscillators

Consider a pendulum with a flexible connecting rod. When initializing the free motion, the bob would be released at a position such that the connecting rod is flexed as shown in the figure. There are two *coupled* motions of interest, one being that of the bob and the other being the vibration of the connecting rod. Will the frequency of oscillation of the pendulum and connecting rod synchronize over several oscillations of the pendulum ?

The question suggests a conjecture based on [Strogatz's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=811&v=aSNrKS-sCE0&feature=youtu.be) which discusses synchrony in nature.

[image]

Comment: *Over several oscillations of the pendulum will the frequency of oscillation of the pendulum and connecting rod synchronize?* What have you tried that makes you think that?

Comment: It is a conjecture based on [Strogatz's talk](https://youtu.be/aSNrKS-sCE0?t=811) and the fact that the frequencies are $f_{pend} \propto \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$ and $f_{rod} \propto \sqrt{\frac{1}{l}}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: How did you obtain the relation $f_{rod} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{l}}$?

Comment: I apologize, I meant $f_{rod} \propto \frac{1}{L}$ based on a simplistic model of a [string vibrating with fixed ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration).